# how to store input from tkinter to database

Tags: python-3.x

i am making a simple signup app using core python but i dont know how to store the input data to database plz help me..here is my code ..here i had taken 4 entries for input data that is first name ,last name, email id, password.. and also a button but the only problem arise is that how to store these input value to the database.

```
from tkinter import *

o = Tk()


m1 = Label(text='First Name :')
m1.pack()

t1 = Entry()             # creating 4 entries for input data
t1.pack()
###
m2 = Label(text='Last Name:')
m2.pack()

t2 = Entry()
t2.pack()

m3 = Label(text='E-mail:')
m3.pack()
t3 = Entry()
t3.pack()

m4 = Label(text='Password:')
m4.pack()
t4= Entry()
t4.pack()


##
def event():  #creating button

     cid = t1.get()

     name = t2.get()

     email = t3.get()

     password = t4.get()

     print('your account is created')

     print('Full name is: ',cid,name)

     print('E-mail is: ',email)

     print('Password is: ',password)

b1 = Button(text='Sign up',command=event)

b1.pack()




o.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get started working with databases, you are going to want to check out one of the following links depending on the version of Python you are using:

Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html  <-- It looks like you are using this version of Python.

Python2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Note: This is the documentation for sqlite3 specifically.

As you have only specified that you want to store information in a database, it is hard to give more information other than point you in the right direction based on what your are trying to do.